# Is it possible to check if two classes have the same members

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

```
struct Test1 : public Base {
    enum { type = 1 };
    int a;
    char ch;
    virtual void func1();
};

struct Test2 : public Base {
    enum { type = 2 };
    int a;
    char ch;
    virtual void func1();
};
```

I'm developing a project with C++14. For some compatibility reason, I have to declare two classes as above, whose members are exactly the same.

My question is if there is some metaprogramming method, which allows me to check if the two classes have exactly the same members?

**real issue**

Yeah, I know it's so weird but I did get such an issue...

I'm developing a web server, each class above is a protocol.

Now the problem is that some Android developer has wrongly used the protocol `Test1`, so we can't touch it as users may not update their App. What I could do is just add another protocol. So I add the class `Test2`.

Since the two protocols do the exactly the samething, I want to make sure that they are always the same. Meaning that if someone adds a member into `Test1` someday but he forgets to add the member into `Test2`, I want to get a compile-time error.

BTW, I only care about the data member, not member function.

Comment: These classes have different members. If you want two classes with exactly the same members then you should create a base class with all the members and then inherit it without adding anything new.

Comment: @user7860670 You mean the enum member is different?

Comment: No, i mean that all the members are different.

Comment: Beware the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need two classes that are exactly the same?

Comment: Given a specific member name, you can probably check if two different classes contain this member

Comment: @Thomas I'm developing a web server, the android developer told me that I had to add a new class for a same API (which is a protocol in fact) because of some compatibility issue.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Why would the _internals_ of your C++ web server affect the code of an Android client? At the HTTP level, there's no such thing as a class.

Comment: @user7860670 I did try to inherit a base class, but my problem is that I must keep the members of the two classes the same ALWAYS. The inheritance can't ensure that. I mean if someday a developer add a member for one of them, I want to generate a compile time error.

Comment: @Thomas It's all because some developer used wrongly the protocol three years ago. Now I can't change it because some user may never update their app, you know what I mean? I have to make sure the the old version always works. So I can't change the old protocol.

Comment: The class is not the protocol. But let's pretend that it is. Then the duplication might be a fine solution: one of the classes is for backwards compatibility and will never change; the other moves forward and may be changed. So why do you then need a check that they are fully identical?

Comment: With this logic if someday a developer adds a member in both of them then generating c compile time error won't be possible. And most likely you don't need two classes anyway. Spreading copypasta is never a good idea.

Comment: @Thomas My company has its own protocol system. In the backend developer's view, a class with a unique enum is jsut a protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the premise of this question because it is essentially asks for a way to keep code duplication. However in practice shit happens and if someone wants two classes with the same content the better idea would be not to declare two classes and then check them for compatibility, but to declare them just once. This can be done by using a base class or by using preprocessor. The latter case will also prevent any new members from sneaking into derived classes while adding new members into both classes with require just a single modification:

```
#define MAKE_CLASS(mp_name) \
struct mp_name : public Base { \
    enum { type = 1 }; \
    int a; \
    char ch; \
    void func1(); \
};
MAKE_CLASS(test1)
MAKE_CLASS(test2)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to check if two classes have the same members

If you can upgrade to C++20, and if the classes are standard layout, and you aren't concerned about exact matches for types, but rather layout compatibility - such that one class might have a const member while the other has non-const - then you can use the `std::is_layout_compatible` type trait.

Otherwise, you may have to resort to meta-programming.

---

> I want to make sure that they are always the same.

Regarding the XY-problem, if you can change `Test1` in an API compatible way, then inheritance could be a solution:

```
struct TestData : Base {
    int a;
    char ch;
};

template<int type>
struct TestBase : TestData {
    enum { type = type };
};

struct Test1 : TestBase<1> {
    void func1();
};

struct Test2 : TestBase<2> {
    void func1();
};
```

If you cannot touch `Test1` at all, then a hacky workaround would be to use it as a base:

```
struct Test2 : Test1 {
    enum { type = 2 };
    void func1();
};
```

It's not ideal due to the implicit conversions. You could avoid those by using private inheritance, but then you have the problem of shared public non-virtual `Base`.

Comment: Nice one. Sorry I just re-edited my question and the classes contain virtual functions... So I think they are not standard layout anymore. My bad. I did forget `std::is_layout_compatible`. Nice one man.